# Aborting ArcPy script manually once it has started running in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I was writing some script and it involved processing a large number of rasters. I hit run and then noticed an parameter I forgot to change.

Is there a way to cancel the script once it has begun so I don't have to either wait for it to finish or close ArcMap?

Comment: If the script is run within the geoprocessing framework, and checks are done in the app for the cancel button being pushed, then you can handle this gracefully.  If it's a standalone Idle (or other IDE) interpreter, then a break might work. After that you're falling back to killing the Python interpreter or Desktop session.  I try always add a check for a "stop.now" file at the top of my list processing (`if os.path.exists('stop.now'): break`), so I have a graceful way to exit long-running loops.

Comment: It's possible if you are using progressor bar.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the [advice of @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389618/aborting-arcpy-script-manually-once-it-has-started-running-in-arcmap#comment638096_389618):

> If the script is run within the geoprocessing framework, and checks
> are done in the app for the cancel button being pushed, then you can
> handle this gracefully.  If it's a standalone Idle (or other IDE)
> interpreter, then a break might work. After that you're falling back
> to killing the Python interpreter or Desktop session.  I try always
> add a check for a "stop.now" file at the top of my list processing
> (`if os.path.exists('stop.now'): break`), so I have a graceful way to
> exit long-running loops.

or [that of @FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389618/aborting-arcpy-script-manually-once-it-has-started-running-in-arcmap#comment638099_389618):

> It's possible if you are using progressor bar.

I have not tested but I think both would work.